# Converting a double into a int.. can i remove the numbers after the point?

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert an item from a text box which contains double numbers such as "1.1". Is there a way in which I can format this, so that the ".1" will be removed and it can be assigned to the variable "points"?

Is there a way in which I can convert an item from the text box "txtTotal" which inside it will contain "1.1" to be formatted to hold the numbers before the point and then be assigned into the points variable, and points will then output "1"?

```
int points;

txtTotal.Text = string.Format("£{0:0}");
points = Convert.ToInt32(txtTotal.Text);
MessageBox.Show("{points}");
```

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you specify your input value and expected output value?

Comment: What's wrong with `Convert.ToInt32` (or simply casting to `int`)?

Comment: ive tried to make it clearer tilak, and john the infromation inside the text box will contain a double as a string if that makes sense :/

Comment: Have you tried `MessageBox.Show(points)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `Split` the Text on the decimal point, then remove the `£` from the first array index using `TrimStart`., and I would use `int.TryParse` to check if the output is valid.

Like this:

```
int points;
txtTotal.Text = string.Format("£{0:0}",txtTotal.Text);
if(int.TryParse((txtTotal.Text.Split('.')[0].TrimStart('£')),out points))
   MessageBox.Show(points.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to remove all digits after the decimal point, use `Math.Truncate();`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c2eabd70(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: or Math.Round() depending on the scenario

Comment: yes but how do i do this if the numbers are held in a text box?

Comment: @Bunion double d = double.Parse(textbox.Text);  -> int x = (int)Math.Truncate(d);

Comment: Better use `Double.TryParse` in case the `textbox.Text` is not a number.

Comment: Better yet, use a numericUpDown contol.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to extract the *fractional* portion of the *floating-point* (`double`) value, with the string format of a *currency*.

I would do something like this:

```
using System.Globalization; // For NumberStyles enum

var currencyString = txtTotal.Text;

// Parse the TextBox.Text as a currency value.    
double value;
var parsedSuccesfully = double.TryParse(currencyString,
                                        NumberStyles.Currency, 
                                        null,
                                        out value);

// TODO: Handle parsing errors here.

var wholePounds = Math.Truncate(value);
var fractionalPounds = (value - wholePounds);

// Get the whole and fractional amounts as integer values.
var wholePoundsInteger = (int)wholePounds;
var fractionalPoundsInteger = (int)(fractionalPounds * 1000.0); // 3 decimal places
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show it in a `MessageBox` you can handle it as string:

```
string points = txtTotal.Text;
points = points.Substring(0, points.IndexOf("."));
MessageBox.Show(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text itself will be of a currency format (pounds, by the looks of it), you should first get the raw string and convert it to decimal by specifying a NumberStyle of currency, and the appropriate culture (e.g. for en-GB):

```
string rawText = txtTotal.Text;
decimal currencyValue = Decimal.Parse(rawText, NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

finally, truncate (or round, if you want rounding) using the Math methods:

```
int finalValue = Math.Truncate(currencyValue);
```

If it's not in currency format, and is just plain double format, then a more straightforward parse to a double will suffice:

```
double doubleValue = Double.Parse(txtTotal.Text);
int finalValue = Math.Truncate(doubleValue);
```

If the format is not consistent, it may be worth using the `TryParse` method (instead of the direct `Parse`) to deal with any parsing issues first.